# Is TestActorRef deadlock possibility still relevant?

Tags: scala, testing, akka

In akka 2.3.9 [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/testing.html) there is a warning:

> Any message send from a `TestProbe` to another actor which runs on the 
>   `CallingThreadDispatcher` runs the risk of dead-lock, if that other actor 
>   might also send to this probe. The implementation of `TestProbe.watch` and 
>   `TestProbe.unwatch` will also send a message to the watchee, which means 
>   that it is dangerous to try watching e.g. `TestActorRef` from a `TestProbe`.

I tried to reproduce the described deadlock situation in test using `TestProbe` and `TestActorRef` as both are using `CallingThreadDispatcher`

```
class DeadlockTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem()) with FunSuiteLike {
  test("deadlock attempt") {
    val b = TestProbe()
    val a = TestActorRef(new Actor {
      override def preStart() = b.ref ! "pre"
      def receive = {
        case msg =>
          sender ! msg
          context.stop(self)
      }
    })
    b.watch(a)
    b.send(a, "foo")
    b.expectMsg("pre")
    b.expectMsg("foo")
    b.expectTerminated(a)
    b.unwatch(a)
  }
}
```

I expected the test to hang but it successfully passed.

Is the warning still relevant and the possibility of deadlock is high or is it outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The race condition that this warning speaks about is inherent in the TestProbe’s design but the probability of hitting the deadlock is rather small, the watch must occur exactly at the same time as sending a message in the other direction and both must happen in different threads. The latter can in rare cases be observed due to the way top-level actors are created.

All of this is rather tricky and none of this applies to the way tests are written and conducted for Akka Typed, I'm looking forward to when that is the only mode that is used.